# Can't redirect back to my app amplify signInWithWebUI

Tags: android, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-sdk-android

I'm trying to implement AWS sign in with web UI on my app, followed the [documentation](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/signin_web_ui/q/platform/android/) and it's working fine but I can't redirect back to my app after sign in.

In my amplifyconfiguration.json :

```
"Auth": {
                "Default": {
                    "OAuth": {
                        "WebDomain": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
                        "AppClientId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                        "SignInRedirectURI": "http://localhost:3000/",
                        "SignOutRedirectURI": "http://localhost:3000/",
                        "responseType": "code",
                        "Scopes": [
                            "phone",
                            "email",
                            "openid",
                            "profile",
                            "aws.cognito.signin.user.admin"
                        ]
                    },
                    "authenticationFlowType": "USER_SRP_AUTH"
                }
            }
```

When I change `"SignInRedirectURI": "http://localhost:3000/"` to `"SignInRedirectURI": "myapp//"` instead of the login page it shows this error:

[image]

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You have to pull the amplify auth again or make changes in your awsconfiguration.json and amplifyconfiguration.json file to change the redirect URL.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).